# Android disable divider in Custom adapter

Tags: android

i can not disable divider in custom adpater. my xml layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#464646"
              android:showDividers="none">
</LinearLayout>
```

i'm try to disable that with programical but that does not work for me.

[image]

**UPDATED POST:**
custom Adapter:

```
public class ReceivedAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ReceivedItemStructure> row;

    private TextView tv_smsBody;
    private TextView tv_smsSender;
    private TextView tv_smsDate;

    public ReceivedAdapter(Context context, List<ReceivedItemStructure> row)
    {
        this.row = row;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
}
```

Comment: @Manish i dont have ListView. i have custom adapter

Comment: can u show your custom layout of the listview

Comment: @Spry Techies i dont have any listview in XML y app using custom . post updated

Comment: Show your main xml file

Comment: ya i got that have u added earlier any dividers in that customadapter if not check your margintop of the custom layout

Comment: it is not a divider it is margin i think

Answer (score 0):

From [ListView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) you have to :

```
getListView().setDivider(null);
```

from code or from xml :

```
android:divider="@null"
```

The same code can be used in a LinearLayout as well

Answer (score 0):

make listview with this way,

```
android:divider="@null"
```

this line show by list view default